# Can update .fill_betweenx() arguments? How?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm aware that it's possible to update the x and y values of a plot by using its artist with `.set_xdata()` and `.set_ydata()`.

Can something similar be done with **`.fill_betweenx()`** to update its arguments ( `y, x1, x2` and `where` ) to avoid clearing the axes and plotting it again?

Comment: you probably need `set_paths`, but its unlikely to be as straightforward as updating a `plot` instance

Comment: I'm not aware of a straightforward way to do this. Best I've come up so far is to remove only the `fill_between` artist from the plot with `remove` method and re- plot the `fill_between`. At least, it doesn't clear the entire content of the axe. Would like to know if there is a better way as well.

Answer (score 2):

It is somewhat a hack, there is a `set_path` method for the `PolyCollection` that `fill_between` returns, but it seems not to be functional. Have to directly assign new `Path` to `_path`:

```
from matplotlib.path import Path

x = [0,2,3,4,5]
y = [1,4,5,6,7]
z = [4,5,6,7,8]
PC = plt.fill_between(x, y, z)
PC._paths = [Path(np.vstack([[1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,4,3,2,1,1],
                             [4,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,7,6,5,4,4]]).T,
                   np.array([1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,9]))]
```

Before

[image]

After

[image]